# unwanted response - navigationlink cycles through all pages

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui-navigationlink

I am doing a project where I've got some codes I am confused about. its an app to track user's habits, ContentView has a page with a list of habits, each has its own page (HabitPage) showing more detail using navigationLink.

navigationLink worked fine to show a habit page at first, but what I intend to do is the following:

1. user clicks a button to increase the number of times a habit is done
2. when the number of times its done reaches the goal, I want the app to show an alert,  saying the goal's achieved
3. App to jump back to ContentView

I managed to do 1,2 but not 3, in my HabitPage I added an Environment var to be dismissed and a Bool to toggle. The Bool is tied to an observableobject class on a separate page. I added the Bool to navigationLink on isActive. Now what it does is that it's cycling through all the HabitPage after clicking into one from ContentView. Can someone explain the logic behind to me as I am lost to what caused it. thanks

ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var habitsCV = DataShare()
   
- function for deletion
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                //background
                List {
                    ForEach (habitsCV.allHabitGeneral, id: \.name) { each in
                        **NavigationLink(destination: habitView(habitHV: self.habitsCV,singleHabit: each), isActive: self.$habitsCV.isShowingHabit) {**
- stuff for describing the habit
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                .onDelete(perform: itemRemove)
                }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            - buttons, another sheet which works fine and nav bar title
        }
    }
}
```

HabitPage

```
struct habitView : View {
    
    **@ObservedObject var habitHV : DataShare**
    var singleHabit : AllHabits
    **@Environment(\.self.presentationMode) var presentationMode**
    
-function for the app
    
    var body : some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                - text for descriptions of the habit
                
                Button("increase timesDone") {
                    var o : Int = 0
- function to retrieve array index o
                            if self.habitHV.allHabitGeneral[o].timesDone > self.habitHV.allHabitGeneral[o].completionGoal {
                                -lines for alert
                                **self.habitHV.isShowingHabit = false**
                                **self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()**
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
-alert
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the class storing the Bool

```
class DataShare : ObservableObject {
- alert messages and another Boolean for a functional sheet
    
    **@Published var isShowingHabit : Bool = false**

    @Published var allHabitGeneral : [AllHabits] {
-didSet function

- initialiser
```